# Connecting to Linux MongoDB from Windows using Kerberos

Tags: c#, linux, mongodb, security, active-directory

I am having trouble connecting to MongoDb using kerberos authentication.
I have created a keytab and added it to the keytabs folder.

My installation of MongoDb is located at:

```
/opt/mongodb/
```

I can generate a token from the Kerberos server using kinit and specifying the keytab located at: `/opt/mongodb/keytab`, this successfully generates a keytab for the FID: SOMEFID/XXXHOST

```
kinit -k -t ost_linux_mongo.keytab SOMEFID/XXXHOST
```

Through the shell, I can then login to the database using the following command:

```
./bin/mongo --authenticationMechanism=GSSAPI --authenticationDatabase=\$external -u SOMEFID/XXXHOST@XXXDOMAIN XXXHOST/admin --ssl
```

The login works without issues.

However the issue is that when I attempt the same via the windows machine using the following config:-

```
var credential = MongoCredential.CreateGssapiCredential("SOMEFID/XXXHOST@XXXDOMAIN","pass");
var settings = new MongoClientSettings
{
Credentials = new[]
{ credential }
,
Server = new MongoServerAddress("XXXHOST", 32017),
UseSsl = true,
VerifySslCertificate = false,
};
client = new MongoClient(settings);
server = client.GetServer();
return server.GetDatabase("admin");
```

Initialization method DataStatsTest.MongoDbCrudTest.SetUp threw exception.

MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: Unable to connect to server XXXHOST: Unable to initialize security context. Ensure the username and password are correct.. ---> MongoDB.Driver.Communication.Security.MongoSecurityException: Unable to initialize security context. Ensure the username and password are correct. --->

MongoDB.Driver.Communication.Security.Mechanisms.Sspi.Win32Exception: No authority could be contacted for authentication. The domain name of the authenticating party could be wrong, the domain could be unreachable, or there might have been a trust relationship failure..

Comment: Did you resolve this issue and would you mind sharing the details.. We're experiencing similar issues and thought your input might be valuable..

Comment: Sorry we decided to go with native Mongo Authentication since our entire company decided this approach is not feasible.